# mysql select query calculation according to given period of time

Tags: mysql

I need a help in mysql :

I'm having a table like

```
name      amount    installment date
abc       1000         5        03/09/12
xyz       5000         2        01/08/12
```

now i need to pivot this table like

like month will populate in this way date+installment like upto month january in case of abc and upto sep in case of xyz

resulting output will be

```
name   amount   month
abc    1000     sep-2012
abc    1000     oct-2012
abc    1000     nov-2012
abc    1000     dec-2012
abc    1000     jan-2013
xyz    5000     aug-2012
xyz    5000     sep-2012
```

anybody suggest me the way for doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you expect to get the additional installment dates from? What if they missed one? so you cant just do month - installmentnumber..?

Comment: date range we can take from month and date_add(month,interval installment month) like in case of abc date range will be between month(_date) and date_add(_date,interval 5 month) that is from september to january.